# Adding a card on Apple Wallet when in landscape causes a crash

Tags: ios, swift, screen-orientation, passkit, apple-wallet

I have a button that adds a wallet card on tap.

It is working well in iPhone devices. The orientation for iPhone devices is locked to portrait mode only.

In iPad devices however which is locked in landscape mode only, tapping the add to apple wallet button causes the app to crash and produce this error:

> Thread 1: "Supported orientations has no common orientation with the
> application, and [PKAddPassesViewController shouldAutorotate] is
> returning YES"

I suspect that the PKAddPassesViewController does not support landscape mode but I maybe wrong.

Comment: You are correct. You will need to allow portrait orientation for the view controller that is adding the pass.

Answer (score 0):

Apple wallet is only available in iPad currently that's why it crashed.